# Subdomain Rewrite Logic

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have the following Rewrite Logic, and it's working to redirect the subdomain, partially. If I visit the URL http://subdomain.clientcollabhq.com/some/path it redirects properly, but if I visit http://subdomain.clientcollabhq.com/ it skips the RewriteCond blocks for the subdomain and falls into the fallback RewriteRule. Any idea what's going on?

```
#
# ClientCollabHQ
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    ServerName clientcollabhq.com
    ServerAlias *.clientcollabhq.com

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/dropbox/My Dropbox/ClientCollabHQ/www/html"
    ErrorLog "D:/wamp/www/dropbox/My Dropbox/ClientCollabHQ/www/logs/error.log"

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.clientcollabhq\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.clientcollabhq\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?subdomain=%2&kohana_uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

Regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which section you meant by "fallback", but for the URL http://subdomain.clientcollabhq.com/, one of the following conditions will be true (I'm fairly certain it's the `-d`, because the `DirectoryIndex` shouldn't have been applied yet I think):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
```

The reason for this is that your subdomain points to your site root, which happens to be a real resource. Since the conditions are true, no rewrite is done, and you should end up at `index.php` with no arguments. You could work around this by adding another condition to the first set, which would make sure that something other than the root is requested before short-circuiting the later rules.

For instance:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Works exactly how it should now. Thanks!